Question on Conformality from Ahlfors, Page 73
Let $f$ be a continuous function on a complex domain $\Omega$ and let $z_0 \in \Omega$. The author asserts that it is clear that "both kinds of conformality" (namely, the fact that angles are preserved by $f$ at $z_0$ and the fact that short line segments with initial point $z_0$ are scaled irrespective of their terminal endpoint in the limit by some fixed scalar $k$) imply that $f'(z_0)$ exists. Why is this clear? What argument was the author imagining?
